# Plaid link: After successfully completing the link flow, onSuccess in not being called

Tags: plaid

I have a working implementation of plaid link, where I was successfully able to connect User's bank account.
Now for last few days, without any changes from my side, the implementation has stopped working.

(in Sandbox environment)
The link flow, happens successfully when the user clicks on "Continue" button on the Plaid's SDKs success screen, it comes back to my app, but the onSuccess method is not called.
When I am checking logs on Plaid Dashboard, I am able to see an entry of Type with Description "HANDOFF - onSuccess", but the onSuccess Callback is not getting called.

Comment: Some info that would help narrow things down:
Which Link SDK are you using? (web, iOS, React, etc.)
If you check the activity log in the Plaid Dashboard, do you see the onSuccess callback there?
Which institution are you using? If it's one that triggers an OAuth flow, can you see if the problem reproduces with an institution that doesn't trigger an OAuth flow?
What happens if you try testing in development rather than Sandbox -- does the problem still happen?